# Find a good starting point to search for $n$ consecutive composite numbers.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

I'd like to use the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) (PNT) to find a good starting point to search for $n$ consecutive composite numbers.

The PNT says

> For large enough $x$, the probability that a random integer not greater
> than $x$ is prime is very close to $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$.

Since the probability of being prime is  $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ then the probability of being composite (not prime) is $1 - \frac{1}{\ln(x)}$.

To find $n$ consecutive composite numbers with probabilities $x, x + 1, x + 2, ..., x + n - 1$, multiplying yields the probability of finding $n$ consecutive composite numbers starting from $x$

$$P(x) \approx \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\ln(x + k)}\right)$$

The goal is to achieve $P(x) \approx 1$ which implies there's a **high probability** of finding consecutive composites. For example,

let $n=3$, $x=100$

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(100)}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(101)}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(102)}\right) \approx 0.48$$

let $n=3$, $x=10000000000$

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(10000000000)}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(10000000001)}\right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{\log(10000000002)}\right) \approx 0.78$$

so choosing $0.78$ is the better choice.

Is there a method to find a good starting value for $x$? I guess setting $x$ to a [Googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) would increase the odds, but verifying the composites would probably take [Deep Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) $7\frac{1}{2}$ million years to compute and check the answer. ;)

Comment: There are classic ways to find large runs of consecutive composite numbers, either by using the construction $n!+2,n!+3,\dots,n!+n$, or by using the Chinese remainder theorem. Are you specifically trying to avoid those methods?

Comment: If you want $n=3$ consecutive composite numbers, then $8$ is an excellent starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x$ is large compared to $n$, $\ln(x)$ is a very good approximation to $\ln(x+k)$.  So  $$P(x) \approx \left(1 - \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right)^n$$
If you want that to be $1-\epsilon$, say, you'll want $$\ln(x) \approx
\frac{1}{1 - (1-\epsilon)^{1/n}}$$
If $\epsilon$ is small, this in turn can be approximated by
$$ \frac{1}{1 - (1 - \epsilon/n)} = \frac{n}{\epsilon}$$
So you might try $x \approx e^{n/\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 2):

If
$\#(n)$
is the product of the first $n$ primes
(sometimes called the
"primorial"),
then
$\#(n+1)+k$
for
$k=2$ to $n+1$
are not prime
since the smallest prime
dividing each $k$
also divides
$\#(n+1)$.

Therefore
$\#(n+1)+1$
starts a string of
$n$ consecutive composites.
Since
$\ln(\#(n))
\approx n$
(according to Chebychev
and the prime number theorem),
$e^{n+1}$ will approximately do.

We can use the explicit bounds in
"Explicit Bounds for Some Functions of Prime Numbers"
by Rosser
to get an explicit bound.

Of course the probabilistic bound
in Robert Israel's answer
is almost certainly
a more accurate bound.